# Can I run SQL queries referencing Excel columns through Power Query?

Tags: sql, excel

I would like to run an SQL query through Excel, that uses one of the sheets column as input.
Example:

```
Select * from {Excel.Income} a
inner join {SQL.Table.Column} b
on a.Name = B.Name
```

Is is possible? I am using SQL server.[image]